# Alternative to backticks for keyboard without backticks?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, internationalization, keyboard

I'm using an Italian keyboard so I do not have backticks. The problem for me is not when I'm writing a question, because I can use the UI of course, but when I'm writing a comment I have to use the keyboard to format my text.

I know the Ctrl+K shortcut, but it's not working on comments, to me at least. I was wondering if there is an alternative char?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that there's any keyboard layout that doesn't have backticks. They're used in a couple of programming languages after all.

Comment: Yep, we exist. It's called 'accento grave' in my language (italian) and it's not used alone. We have the _àèìòù_ directly. Alt+96 is the code to print `

Comment: @sepp2k: That's just a sign that the language designers didn't consider all their potential users. Apparently the C# designers *considered* using the back-tick for something (verbatim string literals, perhaps? Not sure) but rejected them *precisely* because they were awkward to type for some users.

Comment: So basically any Italian who wants to write a shell script has to switch his keyboard layout or type the backtick using a symbol table? That's... troubling.

Comment: @sepp2k a little bit. Should I retag to feature-request or something?

Comment: Same for me - there's no backtick on my ipad keyboard

Comment: While this doesn't really answer your question, I think you should switch to the enUS layout. Programming with it is much easier, and you'll encounter less problems in the long run. I'm Italian too and have used the enUS layout for over a decade now, and I don't regret my choice. You can do accents with apostrophes, for example `però` => `pero'`, it's not the same but I don't think anyone I talked to ever noticed the difference (or at least, no one ever pointed it out)

Comment: @sepp2k: The iPhone OS keyboard doesn't have the backtick either.

Comment: @Kop: yeah, that could be a solution. I actually saw once an italian keyboard with an additional US-layout (like blue chars for [Fn] on a notebook keyboard).

Comment: @Jon The problem extends all the way to the Markdown specifications - http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/, so I don't think its going to be a easy fix for this problem. Truthfully speaking there aren't *that* many single characters left that are not used by computer languages and universal at the same time.

Comment: What's wrong with using Alt+96?

Comment: @Lady: that it's more time consuming. No one said it's impossible to type the character, they are only saying it's not as easy as it should be.

Comment: @Lady: as I said, it's just not handy nor user-friendly.

Comment: I'm Italian too, and have the same problem. I use code in comments a lot, what I do is click on the help link, then copy the backtick character and keep it in the clipboard to have the CTRL-V at will. Of course it would be better to have a key with that symbol always available.

Comment: Just incase anyone stumbles across this, on a windows platform there's the [Microsoft keyboard layout creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665) which allows you to remap things out. You could manually reassign your layout to have backquote as say, AltGr + ' if you wanted?

Comment: @KennyTM Yes it does.

Comment: @Undo That comment is over 3 years old, it's feasible that iOS didn't have such a key back then.

Comment: @Stijn I know... I just saw an current-inaccuracy and needed to correct it :)

Comment: As an alternative to en-US, might I suggest en-UK? Just as handy for programmers, has a € symbol and a backtick, and reasonable ways to enter accented characters on Windows. (In Windows, backtick is a dead key, meaning you have to add a space after it for it to appear. This is used for grave accents. I think Ubuntu can be configured to behave similarly, but I haven't bothered, as I use acute accents significantly more frequently than grave.)

Comment: I have previously utilised multiple keyboards, one UK one and one in the character set I needed for a specific job, with USB it is much easier than in the days when my keyboards had a 5pin din and PS2 connections and would not pick up changes after the OS had booted.  that way you can have a cheap keyboard to handle the keys you need more easily, and use your native higher quality keyboard for the rest of your typing delectation.  Obviously this is not ideal for laptops, but can work excellently for desktops/towers.

Comment: @sepp2k: For shell programming, you can usually use `$(...)` rather than the backtick syntax. (Unless you're using csh/tcsh (don't) or a very old Bourne shell.)

Comment: Backtick escapes are not the whim of SO team, they are the part of the syntax f.g. in bash. Keyboard without it is simply misfit for programmer, it's like not having { and }

Comment: Is there ANY sign that appears on all / most keyboards and yet is not used in natural English language?

Comment: @Mołot The pipe symbol? | - I've never heard of a use for it in natural language. Backslash, too.

Comment: @sq33G actually, vertical bar seems to have many uses outside computing. I use it mostly to mark absolute values in computation, so assigning a function to it could possibly screw things on math site? Also, it's a symbol used a lot in programming, so making it end code lines would be kinda disastrous - a lot, lot of escaping required. And about escaping - that's the reason backslash cannot have that function, as doubling "end of code" with "escape" would only confuse.

Comment: @Mołot ah, didn't realize that you were asking if there were any characters left on the keyboard that would be better for escaping code formatting than the backtick

Comment: @sq33G that's what all this discussion is about, isn't it? ;) So I just didn't see a reason to repeat it.

Comment: Use [US AltGr International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#US_international) (and get a matching keyboard). It's perfect for writing English and programming and, after some time, definitely usable for other languages, at least such that use basically roman letters. (I write German and Swedish with good success.)

Comment: +1 I didnt know about CTRL+K :)

Answer (score 13):

I have almost the same problem with the German keyboard.
Switching to an enUS layout, as commented, is not a viable solution, I still have a lot to write in German!
I have to type the <kbd>`</kbd> (accento-grave) followed by a <kbd>space</kbd> to generate a single back-tick. This also works with the Brazilian layout.

EDIT:
not a solution for Italian layout since there have no back-tick key.

if you are using FireFox you can use the [abcTajpu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/abctajpu/) plugin to generate special characters not (easily) available on the keyboard.

EDIT2: corrected above link to point to the corresponding Firefox Add-ons page

Comment: Actually you do not have the same problem. Your keyboard does have a `\``-key. Italian keyboards actually don't have a `\``-key, they have separate keys for à, è etc. (this was news to me, too).

Comment: I think he was referring to the Brazilian layout not the German one about the `-key.

Comment: @sepp - you are correct, I didn't know that the Italian keyboard does not have a back-tick. Both German and Brazilian layouts have it. I edited the answer to include another option: abcTajpu.

Comment: I'm italian an ALT + 9 output: `

Comment: @Charlie  [That's specific to your OS.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76360/backticks-on-comments/76369#76369)

Comment: It worked for me in Lubuntu and I guess it works for Ubuntu too.

Comment: abcTajpu seems like a broken link nowdays...

Answer (score 7):

I recently made a jquery code that that allows typing of unicode symbols using hostrings. You could also use this for typing backticks. You can install it at stackoverflow using a bookmarklet.

You can find the code here as well as instructions how to install it as a bookmarlet:
http://jsfiddle.net/gqL3H/2/

I've now assigned the hotstring `,,` for typing backticks. But feel free to customize it.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working using  `ALT+96` press and hold `ALT` key and type `96` from numpad you will have `

Comment: Working with a numpad is difficult for some laptops.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows, you can use [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) and simply add backticks and other needed characters to your current layout. In Linux it is a bit more complicated due to diversity, but I'm sure similar tools exist. That should be easier than finding a key that is so often used it's on all layouts, but at the same time so rare it's not really needed neither in human language, code or common math.

Comment: Exactly. There are also some predefined programmer's layouts for western languages. We have luck, because Polish keyboard was designed by wise people and it's using normal keyboard as background.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. actually there are many polish keyboard layouts - and we are lucky that "polish - programmers" won the race to be standard in our country :D

Comment: Well, I'm young and I haven't seen any other layout in shop ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszL. we are ≈ same age, but in my primary school we were supposed to get a grip on the computers when I was about 10. DOS 6.22 and arguments about enter vs return on keyboards ;) I had my share of luck our basic practical engineering (or how should we call ZPT in English) teaching included computers, and one of our teachers was in good standings with Warsaw University of Technology...

Comment: Linux has a compose key that lets one enter almost any character.  E.g. I frequently type ``[compose]ooC`` to get `°C`.  Here's a table I use (and it's possible to add your own compositions) [Non-ASCII characters — compose key sequences](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Tables/common)

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to find the backtick in my keyboard. Then, press the keys that would allow me to type it (in my case, <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> ). Finally, press <kbd>space</kbd> and a backtick will appear.

Comment: So that's a dead key; as I understand the original post, it's not there on Italian layouts.

Comment: @pablo: I don't understand your solution.  Can you explain?  What is the `gr` in `alt gr + ]`?

Comment: @iconoclast: There is a key in my keyboard named "Alt Gr". You should press that key, keep pressing and then press ] too to get one backtick. If you go on pressing "Alt Gr" button and press again ], you will get more backticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows you can create your own keyboard layout with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

I removed the dead-key functionality from those two keys, and created my own layout for development.

You can simply download my zip from github, and install the keyboard layout:

https://github.com/kitsunekyo/win-german-dev-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I use linux and so cannot use Alt+96 to get backtick.
Long time found no answer but figured out myself that **Alt-Gr + Shift + 7** following a space generates the wanted backtick character: **`**