# Backticks on comments

Tags: support, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I googled around and i couldn't find any solution. I'd like to use the (`) in the comments but i don't really know what is the keyboard sequence to achieve it. I'm using an Italian/European keyboard. How would I be able to generate the "tick"?

Comment: You managed to make it in this post.  Can you type it?

Comment: I just copied and past the tip on the right.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a backtick (or a tilde, for that matter) on the stock Italian keyboard. It depends on your OS vendor customizations:

- On **Windows**, type <kbd>96</kbd> on your numpad while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I'd [automate](https://superuser.com/questions/29254/automate-gui-tasks) this if possible.
- On **Linux**, press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> (depends on your distro, I think e.g. Arch Linux uses AltGr-9)
- On **Macintosh**, press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard/61483#61483), Italian keyboards don't have the backtick key.

Try alt+96?

Comment: `Well it does,` Alt + 9 is the answer.

Comment: @Charlie That's because of your OS ;)