# Can you add other options for escaping?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to backtick escapes for non-US keyboard?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard)

I know lot of people are having problems with the backtick ` because of their keyboard. (me to I don't have it anywhere)

Considering we are on Stack Overflow and the backtick is one of the most used char to format here why you don't replace it with a character that every keyboard has?

You can easly implement it with a double underscore __ or many other characters other than the d*mn backtick.

Suggesting:

```
|code|
!code!
^code^
==code==
$code$
+code-
++code++
--code--
;;code;;
]code}
(and thousands of other example better than backtick)
```

Why did you use that  backtick (ye i know the shell)

You can leave the backtick as escape plus adding one of the suggested type to be perfectly backward-compatbile

ADD1:

of course i am talking about comments because when posting a question there is the tooblar up there

add2:

why close a suggestion that got +4 votes?

Comment: `Can you add other options for escaping?` There is no escape from SE!

Comment: What locale are you in that your keyboard doesn't have a backtick?

Comment: @arjan @yes123 Keep in mind that expletives are not permitted on these sites: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233

Comment: @Cody Gray: They are legion, what's your point? (I have en_US as an alternate layout for programming purposes - precisely because none of they layouts in my native language has all the necessary characters used when talking to computers) As for the backticks, I see no problem there (esp. since it's the Unix/bash convention for "execute this").

Comment: @Piskvor: I didn't really have a "point". I was simply curious. Those of us here in the US are often oblivious to what folks in the rest of the world have to go through, generally thanks to our own short-sightedness. I wasn't suggesting there was anything wrong with the question, or that the asker was using the wrong layout. I just wasn't aware the character was uncommon on alternate layouts.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard

Comment: @Cody Gray: Ah, thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding. In my case, it would be `cs_CZ`, which has a combining diacritic key in the place where the backtick is on `en_US`.

Comment: *Why did you use that [...] backtick* — because [Markdown does](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)?

Comment: @Pollyanna, very well, but I don't really see your edit making any difference at all.

Comment: You don't have a backtick?  But that would mean... *NO TILDE???*

Comment: @Arjan It's a complex situation primarily involving automated filters some people have to deal with at work (therefore we can't let the expletive stand) and users who feel extraordinarily attached to their choice of words (therefore I can't simply reformat the message to remove them entirely).  It's a poor middle ground, but it's all we've got.  I would hope that @yes123 would consider reformatting the question to completely remove them, but this is the minimum required solution.

Comment: @poll what's wrong with my suggestion?

Comment: @yes123 Nothings wrong with the suggestion itself, thank you for removing the expletives.  As for why it's being closed, it has already been suggested at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard and several people agree that this is similar enough to keep all the discussion in one question, rather than having two questions with essentially the same request.

Answer (score 3):

```
You can always use <code>the code tag</code>. This requires manual 
<code>&lt;HTML encoding&gt;</code> though, unlike `<the backtick>`.
And it won't work in comments.

(The double underscore is __strong__, often rendered as bold.)
```

You can always use `the code tag`. This requires manual 
`<HTML encoding>` though, unlike `<the backtick>`.
And it won't work in comments.

(The double underscore is **strong**, often rendered as bold.)

Comment: But, that would not work in comments: <code>no way</code>.

Comment: I think that **bold** doesn't work as well.. what about <b>bold</b>? Edit: well, it works now. Probably only "HTML" code is disabled in comments then.