# What happened to that user?

Tags: support, chat, user-accounts

While we never were very fond of Tina (renamed "Model" since, I think, yesterday) [this state of affairs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/589622#589622) (all postings removed, and the avatar linking to a somewhat laconic "no user data available" message) is disturbing.

What happened to her?

Comment: the link provided in red on suspended user pages should be read: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/ particularly the part starting with "when users exhibit a pattern of either.."

Comment: @Jeff: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: @Jeff: ok, that makes more sense. But does "makes no effort to learn" warrant a four month suspension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've just found, it seems her account has been suspended for whatever reason:

See below:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/494192/model

Comment: That's a major punishment... wonder what she has done? Couldn't see anything unusual in her questions or comments. Maybe something she said in the chat?

Comment: @Shadow: The only thing I can think of is some comments of mine to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86733/is-mentioning-sex-ok-or-is-it-not/86759#86759). But even we in the chat think it would be gruff to suspend her for her questions, as dumb as they might have been. Many were ignoring her anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: See, and this is why I am against deletions. We are just having the very same discussion again I had with Adam in that comment thread. This just hurts the site badly.

Comment: @sbi what are you talking about? What deletions? (user in this discussion was suspended not deleted)

Comment: @Shadow: I was searching for a comment discussion I knew I had on meta. The above link is all that remains of it. _"Those who forget their history are bound to repeat it."_

Comment: @sbi comments are "third class citizens" in SE. Always were. They should not contain valueable contents to begin with. Anything you want to preserve for future search/read should be moved/copied to a post, or chat, both of which are much less likely to get deleted just like that. Just think of comment as writing on ice: it might survive for a while, but eventually the ice melts and the writing is lost.

Comment: @Shadow: Nice theory. I take it you're currently busy copying the current voluptuous comment discussions to somewhere safe, so we avoid repeating ourselves the next time the Lounge "misbehaves"? Get real, man. Comments do not "melt". Someone goeis there, looks at them, decides that SO would be a better place if we all go around in circles, and actively destroys what was left to be clarified after answers were given. (Or, more often than never, what lead to some of the otherwise inexplicable answers to be given.)

Comment: @sbi true, it takes three ordinary users (50+ rep) or one diamond user to nuke a comment. And true, many people consider comments as noise so they flag nearly all comments they see, including those recent comments we're having, since they're "too chatty" - there's such a flag reason. So true, those comments will melt, maybe tomorrow, maybe in one year, maybe never (Ice Age?) but no, I don't bother to copy them to a safe place since I've already said what I had to say, and if needed will simply say it again.

Comment: @Shadow: Not everybody who has the time to contribute to SO also has the time to keep repeating themselves. I can't count how often I had to defend the book reference question on meta or banged my head against the Merkin idea that sex is something bad. That discussion had some good arguments that could have been recycled. But, hey, I can always leave the madhouse to its inmates. HAND.

Comment: @sbi I get what you're saying, and you can store comments in something like Google Docs/Yahoo Notes etc, then they're stored safely plus you can search them. Not ideal, can be irritating, but totally your call.

Comment: @Shadow: Yeah, and then, when linking to these copies, get accused of having tampered with them. You might be surprised to hear it, bu I'd rather leave you guys to be on your own re your irrational prejudices.