# What happens if the Feeds guy gets flagged for spam/offensive messages?

Tags: discussion, chat, flags

Given the [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102604/133368) [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105053/why-am-i-suspended-from-chatting-for-a-message-thats-from-may-this-year/105244#105244) [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107099/133368) about the problems with flagging in the chat, I just wondered what actually would happen if enough people flagged a message of that [Feeds](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/-2/feeds) guy as spam/offensive.

Would he then be ***banned*** for half an hour, too?

And would that only impede his ability to post about what he's done, or would he actually be blocked from fulfilling his tasks?

Comment: ["@balpha kicks a puppy ):"](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=625894#625894)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a special system user; I'm *pretty sure* it is, IIRC, immune to such things.

Comment: I just tried flagging the Stack Exchange user and he could happily continue relaying system messages and the such.

Comment: @badp: I don't know what powers you have, but the likes of me needs a bunch of companions in order to ban someone by flagging.

Comment: @sbi I'm a mod on chat.SE; my flags are binding