# Please take me off the chat flagging mod list

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opt-Out for chat flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121912/opt-out-for-chat-flags)

**This is a request to be taken off the list of users who can (actually, must) validate chat flags.**

The feature simply isn’t useful. I can’t remember the last time a flag was valid, and there is on average a flag every few minutes. It’s annoying, and it has no offsetting benefit (if that were the case, I could live with the actual annoyance).

It’s a bit like a spam filter with a false-positive rate of 2% in a world without spam.

Comment: The chat flag feature is pretty broken. It doesn't give enough context to reasonably decide on a flag.