# Expletives are not allowed on SE. But which ones?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, profanity

According to Jeff Atwood, [expletives/swearing is not acceptable behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/149926), and can result in suspension.

I'm fine with this, and completely condone this.  One can still convey a rational point without these words.

However, there are...varying levels of expletives.  Some are stronger than others.  Do we ban all of these, even simple almost innocuous 'replacement' ones like "heck"? What about "dang"? Certain f-bombs or c-bombs I can understand, I'm just curious, as it's come up on travel>SE a couple of times (fortunately I no longer have to moderate that though!) :)

**EDIT** - just noticed it's in the [help] as well:

> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on
>   this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

but again, there's no indication of which words.

Comment: I don't know what we should do with all that gosh darn crap! It gets me so frickin' mad!

Comment: @AndrewBarber and sci-fi ones, like 'fra(c/k)king' from BSG.

Comment: I love frakking! Especially when it gets confused with [fracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracking)

Comment: What c-bombs and f-bombs are you talking about? Not everyone abbreviates the same way either

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words

Comment: Guess it depends on what country you live in

Comment: I want to see _full list_ of what is not allowed

Comment: Data points: you are not allowed to spell out “br*infuck” on [so] or [metase]. On the other hand, you're allowed to spell out “Java” and “Microsoft”. “Microsoft” is even allowed on [unix.se]. I think “expat” is banned on [travel.se].

Comment: @Gilles: Why would you bother putting an asterisk in "br*infuck" if you put it in the wrong place?

Comment: @MarkMayo If we ban the scifi expletives, we also have to ban anyone who states their location to be somewhere in Belgium.

Answer (score 27):

Language gets moderated when it has *become a distraction.*

It doesn't have to be [George Carlin's seven words](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dCIKqkIg1w), nor does it have to be [filth floren filth](http://www.funnyordie.com/videos/6ed4154f2a/eddie-murphy-raw-bill-cosby-from-classicstandupfan), to be a distraction. although those are probably good representative samples of the kind of words we're talking about here.  It just has to be a distraction.

The question you should really be asking is "Is this discourse professional?"

People can be offended by different things based on their culture, or based on the context ("it's OK to prick your finger, but not to finger your prick").  Whether you are attacking someone else personally or not matters.  Whether the offensive words are in code makes a difference (Why is this offensive word filter filtering out "fracking" and "poo"?  Oh, I see; the question was edited).

It is for all those reasons that compiling a definitive list of offensive words (and categorically excluding them) is impossible.

Comment: But we can agree that editing "damn" to "darn" does nothing useful (and shouldn't be done), right?

Comment: Sorry, but you're not gonna pin me on specific instances. :)

Answer (score 4):

Swearing is contextual. On Stack Exchange, we are free to speak how we like so long as we are being respectful.

I feel free to discuss the origin of the words "hell," "shit," etc. if it's applicable, appropriate, and respectful. However, saying it *at* people is neither constructive nor respectful.

The same thing applies to the words "heck" and "dang." It's fully possible to be disrespectful with them. If that is the case, then it is unacceptable for Stack Exchange. Otherwise, it's fine.

Just be aware of how you're going to be read.

Comment: Yeah, context does matter.

Comment: It's so tempting to obfuscate "heck" and "dang" here! ;)

Comment: I totally agree it's contextual, but some are offended by the words.  And Jeff's post would seem to indicate it's just not allowed, period.

Comment: @MarkMayo Jeff's word isn't law, and isn't even the most upvoted answer to that question. The reality hasn't been quite as strict.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - perhaps, but it's in the [help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) too.

Comment: @MarkMayo there is a difference in what is allowed in the chat vs. what is allowed in answers. I can say that microsoft sucks all day in the chat, and noone gives a flying duck. Flying ducks (unless literal) in an answer will likely be edited out, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, there's already a [meta post on swearing in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126017/149926).  In Travel chat we're generally lenient about most, unless offensive or extreme.

Comment: @jan what if the question is about ducks which happen to be flying?

Comment: @AndrewBarber "Flying ducks (unless literal) ..."

Comment: The problem with a list like this is that people who want to ask for the carrying capacity of a pair of asses will be very confused (since a pair of butts can not carry too much). Also, people talking about toes of camels will be. Not to mention roosters. Replacing "cracker"s with "Caucasian"s is just weird. I've never heard of the "wrong" interpretation. [Dicks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicks). The link says enough. "Faggot" normally means "bassoon" AFAICT. Flamer = homosexual? No. Just no. "Fucking" is a village. "Fucks" is a soccer player. Yes, I'm going through the list alphabetically.

Comment: "Gay" is now a swear word? "Hell" => "Heck" will turn out absurdly wrong on [christianity.se]. "Jackass" is a movie title and shouldn't be replaced. "Lesbian" => "Homosexual" - hell no. "Munging" => "Sexual act" will be actively harmful on programming sites. Also, what is the correct term for literal nut sacks now? "Penis" is now a swear word? More importantly the term "male genitalia" is not technically correct. "Skeet" = "semen". No. Absolutely not. Ask Jon. Also, ask skeet shooters. "Snatch" is now a term for female genitalia? It White Persons me to see that site being used for autoreplace.

Comment: "testicle" - the same problem as "penis". Don't get me started about blue breasts and great breasts (birds) again (I'm surprised blue-footed boobies didn't get on the list). Wow, some translations use "vagina", but "vagina" itself is considered slang by this list (and yeah, "female genitalia" is inaccurate). The end.

Comment: Since when is anus a swear word?!

Comment: @Jan Impressive. I didn't give the list more than a cursory glance; who knew it would be so inaccurate!

Comment: If you know it's inaccurate, why keep it in the post?