# strange character replacement on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I added a comment to [jQuery ID selector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362216/jquery-id-selector-not-working) but something strange is happening. The end code reads `");` but SO decided to change that to `";);`.

[image: screenshot]

I did not add a `;` in front of the `)`.

To further explain what's happening here, the following:

```
"http://example.com/." http://example.com/.
"http://example.com." http://example.com.
"http://example.com" http://example.com
```

renders as:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Always write code between `\`    \`` (backtick)

Comment: $("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d"); could not recreate

Comment: $("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "[image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d](http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d%22)");  could not re-create with link

Comment: @alpine Though I agree with you, some people don't have back tick on their keyboard. Can you reproduce this on the same post jao posted to, to make sure there aren't differences in comment markdown between meta and SO?

Comment: @Adam Davis Yes, could not re-create [on the same post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362216/jquery-id-selector-not-working)

Comment: @Adam There's a "code sample" button above the editor too

Comment: What i did was, I copied the string from the original post, then pasted it into the comment box (where it looked okay) $("img[id='Char_" + Character + "']").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d"); but now it does the same thing here. it probably is some funny character replacing thing

Comment: @Michael We're talking about comments, and as far as I can see there's no buttons above the comment edit box...

Comment: While I can't reproduce the issue with the given example line of code, it's easy to reproduce with balpha's example below: `"http://xyz.com/a/b/c"` --> "http://xyz.com/a/b/c" So the bug is valid, although users really should be putting code into backticks, as has been discussed before some users don't have backticks on their keyboard, and thus far Stack Exchange has chosen not to implement another method of adding code blocks into comments.  It would seem that either Stack Exchange should fix this bug or add another method to delineate code blocks in comments.

Comment: @adam define "some people don't have backtick on their keyboard". Maybe some people have no letters on their keyboard, either?

Comment: @JeffAtwood http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard

Comment: @AdamDavis. Use RFC 2606 domain names as examples.

Comment: How on earth is this "by design"???? And it doesn't only affect code, but bog-standard links within English text. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252267/chat-adds-arbitrary-semicolon-for-no-apparent-reason et al)

Comment: Similar scenario happened to me, explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300369/231145

Answer (score 18):

To explain what happens here:

```
"http://xyz.com/a/b/c"
```

is turned into

```
&quot;http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot;
```

The auto-linker sees this as a link to `http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot`, so the semicolon is left over, and that's where it suddenly appears from.

Granted, this is isn't exactly the expected result.

Comment: Interesting.  `"http://xyz.com/a/b/c"` does show this issue: "http://xyz.com/a/b/c" It's odd that we can't reproduce it with his code line though...

Comment: &quot;http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot;

Comment: "http://xyz.com/a/b/c"

Comment: Now I can see `;`

Comment: $("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have the auto-linker not even try to create clickable links when the `http` part is not preceded with some whitespace? On the other hand, maybe punctuation such as preceding dots, commas, and... semicolons, still needs to be allowed then, as some don't properly type a space after those, like:http://example.com And when allowing those, the semi-colon in the preceding `&quot;` would still trigger the auto-linking.

Comment: *Granted, this is isn't exactly the expected result.* -> So maybe we could get rid of the `status-bydesign` and give it an `deferred` or `planned`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it

We were trying

```
$("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");
```

But as jao said in the comments

> What i did was, I copied the string
>   from the original post, then pasted it
>   into the comment box (where it looked
>   okay) $("img[id='Char_" + Character +
>   "']").attr("src",
>   "image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d";);
>   but now it does the same thing here.
>   it probably is some funny character
>   replacing thing – jao

The code that jao is copy / pasting is

```
$("img[id=Char_" + Character + "]").attr("src", "http://image.xboxlive.com/global/t.584108a4/tile/0/2800d");
```

As balpha demonstrated in an example

```
"http://xyz.com/a/b/c"
```

is turned into

```
&quot;http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot;
```

The `http://` in the link is the key

Try the code with `http://` and see

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is *fixed*, in that it is working better for all use cases but not perfect in your use case.

As [balpha mentioned 7 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/strange-character-replacement-on-so/83855#83855), the problem is that link extraction happens on HTML and the regular expression that handles it matches `http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot` as a URL in `http://xyz.com/a/b/c&quot;`.  This is because want trailing semicolons to be treated as punctuation.

I've made things a little smarter now in that:

1. We never break up HTML entities when parsing URLs in rendered HTML.
2. We unserialize *trailing* entities from matched strings and try re-evaluating them.
3. We exclude trailing semicolons both before and after trailing entities.

Only trailing entities are considered because of other hacks that I was asked not to break.

The combination works nicely for URLs in quotes in lists.  In your case, things are better in that the there's not a syntax error in your code, but not perfect because the `)` prevents your " from being considered a trailing entity and puts it in the URL.

For code, it's still a best practice to wrap the whole thing in backticks, `` ` ``, especially since the URL matcher strips off the protocol breaking the code in another way.

Comment: "http://example.com/." http://example.com/.
"http://example.com." http://example.com.
"http://example.com" http://example.com