# Links in quotes are escaped improperly in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange character replacement on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/strange-character-replacement-on-so)

[An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819016/how-can-screenshot-be-taken-online-using-java/5819074#5819074):

[image: bad link]

I posted a link in quotes, but the ending quote was interpreted as part of the link and was escaped – mostly. Now the link doesn't work *and* there's a hanging semicolon after it. The semicolon is part of a `&quot;` entity which somehow got partway into the link.

```html
&quot;<a href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html&quot" rel="nofollow">download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html&quot</a>;
```

I assume this isn't a problem in questions and answers, but let's see: "http://google.com"

Comment: And in chat, it seems after some experimentation.

Comment: The solution might be to abstain: http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/