# From where does this semicolon come from?

Tags: support, bug, comments

I have added a comment to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119092/allow-edit-retag-suggestions-for-area-51-meta, and I noticed that my comment contains a semicolon.

> [image: screenshot]

I thought I added it by mistake, but the edit form doesn't show any semicolon.

> [image: screenshot]

From where does the semicolon come? It is not automatically added, as the other comments don't have it, and the dash character is already added at the end of the comment, and before the username of who posted the comment.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: It looks like any link followed by a character that needs to be escaped causes it. E.g. http://www.google.com/< http://www.google.com/&

Comment: The question could be then understood as, "Is that semicolon automatically added?"

Comment: It doesn't seem the case in my comment, though. At least, I don't remember that a period after the URL needs to be escaped.

Comment: Let's try with "This is an easy URL to remember: http://www.ersggreaasdewryprprt.com."

Comment: Uhmmm… The semicolon is added because there is a period after the URL. I guess @MichaelMrozek is right about escaping a character.

Comment: Should this be considered a bug report? After all, it is not what it is supposed to happen.

Comment: I don't think the period matters; it was added because you ended with a double quote (which gets rewritten as `&quot;`). And yes, it's a bug

Comment: I'm 99% certain there's a duplicate of this somewhere on meta.

Comment: Interestingly, chat's client-side Markdown mini parser + auto-linker will handle this case correctly, but the server will then send back the mangled result.

Comment: Also to note, if comments [supported the `<url>` syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112114/urls-wrapped-in-are-not-parsing-correctly-in-comments) it would be possible to manually avoid this scenario, at least.