# Domain names followed by full stops create invalid IDN domain names

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

[A comment of mine](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95995/in-a-sign-language-dictionary-should-video-loop-by-default#comment155429_95995) contains the text `See also: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com‌​.` However, this appears as `See also: languagelearning.stackexchange.com‌​;.` (where did that semi-colon come from?), and it links to `http://languagelearning.stackexchange.xn--com-cn0a/`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I can't imagine what funky software that'd be, @ShadowWizard. I'm running Firefox on Ubuntu with no weird settings. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0`

Comment: From '12: [From where does this semicolon come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119107/from-where-does-this-semicolon-come-from), though that was caused by the `"`

Comment: I only noticed this now, so I can't recall. I think it was, copy URL from address bar, paste, hit backspace to remove trailing slash, type full stop, hit enter to submit comment.

Comment: whoa.. sorry for my assumptions. Turns out it wasn't you indeed.

Comment: I'm going to have to read the suggested dupe more carefully. I was under the impression that it applied only to code.

Comment: This might be a change I pushed today.

Comment: If it is, then this doesn't seem to be a dupe of a '13 question.

Comment: @Sklivvz can you please remove the close votes? I'm afraid it's still in the Close review, and people might miss the fact it's not a dupe. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment.

TL;DR: Regex.

Long version: We introduce a non-visible, optional separator entity every 20 characters to make comments wrap. This has to be removed and taken into account when we linkify URLs. The Regex did not match the last `;` as it's a valid separator for URLs: if you write `http://example.com;` the matched URL should be `http://example.com`. Unfortunately in some rare cases these separators would be introduced just at the right (wrong) spot. In the case linked, the URL with separators inserted ended with a separator and thus a semicolon like so

```
See also: http://languagelearn&zwnj;&#8203;ing.stackexchange.com&zwnj;&#8203;.
```

and so the URL parsed was

```
http://languagelearn&zwnj;&#8203;ing.stackexchange.com&zwnj;&#8203
```

without the trailing `;`. Once we remove the separator this gives

```
http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com&zwnj;&#8203
```

which is what you found the link was pointing to. The semicolon that appears is also because of this.

I've <strike>improved</strike> muchly complicated the regex so it matches the separator at the end but not a normal semicolon.

---

Update: The new regex had other problems. I'm reverting for now, pending a real fix tomorrow. The battle of the regex rages on. I shall prevail.

---

Done.

Comment: Any chance this caused [a new bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283480/link-length-format-in-comments)?

Comment: Yes.. I'm undoing and fixing tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: [Just to make sure you're aware](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/mathjax-is-breaking-in-short-expressions-frequently-today), probably caused by this change.

Comment: @DanielFischer not caused by this, but it has a similar cause