# Link length format in comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I posted a link to the PHP manual here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980871/fetch-mysql-record-using-php, but it got cut off at `http://php.net/manua`. Did the length of links get restricted?

Link from clipboard: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Lets see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Obviously a bug, and a weird one at that. Doesn't look like a fixed length restriction, something with trying to parse by "/" perhaps.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe it's the first step in restoring link shorteners! er... ok you're probably right :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In Oded's link, it gets cut off before the first /

Comment: Might be a side effect of [this other bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283476/152859). /cc @Oded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed, this was due to a "fix" for a different problem. Regexes are hard. Dammit.

Fix going out now.

Comment: I'm sure this will break something else! As is the eternal cycle of bug catching.