# Semi-colon Appended on File location in comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I posted:

> /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files‌​/file_contexts/

as a comment on Server Fault but it came out as:

> /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files‌​7;file_contexts

This seems like it may be related to a bug report I filed last week.

The comment can be seen here: [MySQL Wont Start with Datadir Change](https://serverfault.com/questions/798897/mysql-wont-start-with-datadir-change?noredirect=1#comment1011947_798901)

A test comment on this thread shows a bit different behavior, but still not expected.

Comment: Reproduces? `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files‌​/file_contexts/`

Comment: Link to your previous report, please.

Comment: @AdamLear I see what you mean, here it is, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283480/link-length-format-in-comments and that was somewhat related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283408/domain-names-followed-by-full-stops-create-invalid-idn-domain-names/283476#283476

Comment: According to Sklivvz, that is by design. (Since it's not breaking any links, which is the bug fixed before.)

Comment: Oh, I see, there are more characters there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard seems to be a new bug

Comment: @Sklivvz another regex? :(

Comment: `/This/can/be/a/path/to/a/better/Stack/Exchange/experience!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch, it should be fixed in the next deployment.