# URLs in comments surrounded by double quotes wrongly linkified

Tags: bug, comments, special-characters, auto-linking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange character replacement on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/strange-character-replacement-on-so)

I have made [a comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166120/urls-in-comments-surrounded-by-double-quotes-wrongly-linkified#comment485752_166120) (first comment in this question itself) with this text:

```
Test 1 (without backticks): String myURL = String("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

2 problems here:

1. The displayed text is changed from `http://www.yahoo.com` to `yahoo.com`.
2. The *href* wrongly included a double quote character at the end, making the URL wrong.

*<sup>No problem for the version with backticks.</sup>*

Comment: Test 1 (without backticks): String myURL = String("http://www.yahoo.com");

Comment: Test 2 (with backticks): `String myURL = String("http://www.yahoo.com");`

Comment: So format your code correctly as code...

Comment: Testing: "http://stackoverflow.com" Source: `Testing: "http://stackoverflow.com"`... yeah it's broken. Is it a big deal? Meh.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not much of a big deal, but I'd voice it out anyway. I guess the SO admins can decide whether it's worth fixing.