# URLs in double quotes are not resolved

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

There seems to be a bug inasmuch that there is a disparity between the auto-resolving of Stack Exchange *URLs within double-quotes* contained in posts in normal viewing mode and in edit mode.

Example ([this post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/21096/4762)) in normal viewing mode, showing the URL in double quotes not being resolved:

> [image: URL in double-quotes in view mode]

However, in edit mode, the URL in double-quotes *is* auto-resolved to the title of the post:

> [image: URL in double-quotes in edit mode]

That is to say, in normal viewing mode,

> "https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/z-offset-on-autoleveling-sensor-setup"

should be rendered as

> "[Z Offset on autoleveling sensor setup](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/z-offset-on-autoleveling-sensor-setup)"

Comment: This is already reported: [Link in quotes rendered as title in edit preview mode but as URL in the rendered post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357577/link-in-quotes-rendered-as-title-in-edit-preview-mode-but-as-url-in-the-rendered)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I hadn't seen that one. I had seen [Formatting problems with double quotes in URLs, mostly affecting the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327769/280335) and [URLs in comments surrounded by double quotes wrongly linkified \[duplicate\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166120/280335) but they didn't match what I was seeing. So, this question *is* a duplicate then, after all... oh well. :-)