# Chat adds arbitrary semicolon for no apparent reason

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, security, character-escaping

1. Go to chat
2. Write `"like http://xkcd.com"`
3. Wait a few moments for the submission to go through
4. Resulting text is:

   [image: Random semicolon activity]

I tried a few variations and, as long as the URL is within a quoted passage, and some non-link text is prior within the quote, the semicolon appears.

More [proof](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/22375043/history) that this is a strange bug (as the two blocks in the below image ought to be identical):

[image]

<sub>(Thanks to [the Robot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) for caring more than any human would.)</sub>

Comment: Also please note that my immediately subsequent comment in the original discussion was "no offence".

Comment: I have a feeling this could be exploited in an XSS attack. **Get the SE team *now***.

Comment: awooga awooga..

Comment: Just contacted the team on this. We'll see what they say.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery: I don't get it. Was this post not sufficient notification of the bug?

Comment: Good grief, four years old and still not fixed!

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely an SO-Markdown bug of some sort, since the source is like this:

```
<div class="content">
    like when people go &quot;omg this is so funny <a href="http://xkcd.com&quot" rel="nofollow">xkcd.com&quot</a>; cos they&#39;re too stupid to realise that their link has a shelf life of, at most, three days                      
</div>
```

It's like the `"` has been HTML-encoded before linkification occurs.... *then* linkification goes up to the entity's `;`, leaving `&quot` orphaned (and browsers tend to accept `&quot` rather than `&quot;` because Internet Explorer -5 set a precedent back in the late 1850s).