# Bug in parsing comment's text?

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

I've posted a comment on Stack Overflow, [as you may see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url/17714711#comment78904771_17714711).

The relevant text is the first sentence:

> Note that this RegEx doesn't capture URLs that have subdomains of one letter only, like **"http://m.sitename.com"**.

(In the quote here, it renders fine).

After posting, the end-quote was parsed as part of the URL, but worse (and weirder) than that - a wild semicolon appeared just before the comma. You may see in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The original text of the comment is this, no semicolon there:

[image: Original comment text behind]

I've tried to edit the comment's source text, by adding a space before the comma, but that didn't change anything.