# Accept alternative notation for URLs in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, internationalization

On my keyboard layout, square brackets `[]` require very inconvenient key combinations,

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.

@3ventic, in the comments, says that for his (Finnish?) layout, it's even a triple:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>9</kbd>.

Because of this, I often end up pasting raw URLs into comments instead of making them look nice and fancy using linkified text.

In addition to the standard Markdown, please also accept an alternative notation for linkified text, for example

```
 See <the manual>(http://www.example.com)
```

or

```
 See (the manual)(http://www.example.com)
```

or, in keeping with the notation for E-Mail recipients:

```
See "the manual" <http://www.example.com>
```

It would make things much easier for those of us with non-English keyboard layouts, and it's extremely unlikely any existing content would be adversely affected by this.

Comment: Better than ctrl+alt+8 and ctrl+alt+9...

Comment: @3ventic not sure what you mean. This would simply be an additional alternative?

Comment: No I just meant that your situation is easier than mine.

Comment: Ahh right. Wow, that stinks even more

Comment: You think *you've* got keying problems - I (almost exclusively) use an iphone to post; if you tried entering a url using one of those (no mouse, no ctrl key, alternate keyboards for symbols, press-and-hold for alternate characters, etc) you probably wouldn't be complaining.

Comment: I think SE should produce a special keyboard, like the one my nephew uses for his PC video games.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but at least on Windows, [Alt Gr] == [Ctrl + Alt]. So Pëkka and @3ventic situations are pretty much the same.

Comment: If this is implemented, please also do [Alternative to backtick escapes for non-US keyboard?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61235/alternative-to-backtick-escapes-for-non-us-keyboard) :) Both **[]** and **`** require awkward hand position on [azerty](http://i.imgur.com/l8tnvvv.png)

Comment: @Stijn bounty started - maybe somebody can at least come up with a userscript

Comment: @rsenna true, but I think I've seen keyboards with no `Alt Gr`